# Proxying requests to Tornado with Apache - 502 Error

Tags: python, apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

Trying to figure out why we get `502 ProxyError` on our requests, especially when serving long-running requests on our Python servers.

Our servers are on CentOS, and we use `httpd` to proxy Web requests, which then get routed to a Tornado server running a WSGI REST application (which runs on port 8000).

Generally, requests that do not exceed a certain amount of time succeed, but when the request times out, we get several `502 ProxyError`s after it is done, and our server becomes unresponsive.  We've also seen this behavior when deploying our application to our development servers, which also use `httpd` in the same way.

The configuration of our `httpd.conf` VirtualHost is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server_ip
    ServerAlias server
    ServerAdmin admin@server

            DocumentRoot /var/www/

            ErrorLog /var/www/log/error_log

            LogLevel debug

            # Reverse proxy
            ProxyRequests off
            ProxyPass /rest/ http://server_ip:8000/

            # Rewrites
            <Directory />
                            Order allow,deny
                            Allow from all

                            RewriteEngine On
                            #RewriteRule /rest/(.*) http://server_ip:8000/$1 [L,QSA]
            </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am also seeing entries like this in the server logs:

`....[error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (server_ip)`

What could be causing this situation?  Is there something else (either a different library or configuration) that we should be using here?

I am not sure if the information I have provided here is sufficient, so if there is something else which would be useful, let me know and I'll post it ASAP.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

ProxyPass /rest/ http:// server_ip:8000/ **connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30**

Change the timeouts to whatever suits you best.

More info on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html